# PowerShell Invoke-RestMethod skips a returned null value when navigating through the array values. Ideas?

Tags: arrays, powershell, api, invoke-restmethod, member-enumeration

I am calling an API that returns 3 values in an object "tags", which has values for "tags.name" and tags.results".  The values below are what is returned. But as I try to navigate through the values, I can see that the "null" value, the {}, was not stored in the array.  It just skipped it, but I need this value as it completely ruins the array.

**Any idea how to correctly populate the array so it doesn't skip this {} value?**

```
Response Values

values                      attributes                     
------                      ----------                     
{1605560351000 78.129448 3} @{machine_type=System.Object[]}
{}                                                         
{1605560354000 0 3}         @{machine_type=System.Object[]}

Resulting Array
0 : 1605560351000 78.129448 3
1 : 1605560354000 0 3
2 :
```

The PowerShell nvoke and array code:

```
    $response = Invoke-RestMethod 'https://api' -Method 'POST' -Headers $headers -Body $body

    "Response Values"
    $response.tags.results
    ""
    "Resulting Array"
    "0 : " + $response.tags.results.values[0]
    "1 : " + $response.tags.results.values[1]
    "2 : " + $response.tags.results.values[2]
```

The returned JSON from Invoke-RestAPI.  You can see where the returned value is null for the second node.

```
{
    "tags": [
        {
            "name": "StateComp1",
            "results": [
                {
                    "values": [
                        [
                            1605561152000,
                            75.436455,
                            3
                        ]
                    ],
                }
            ],
        },
        {
            "name": "StateComp2",
            "results": [
                {
                    "values": [],
                }
            ],
        },
        {
            "name": "StateComp3",
            "results": [
                {
                    "values": [
                        [
                            1605561469000,
                            0,
                            3
                        ]
                    ],
                }
            ],
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not specific to [`Invoke-RestMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod) and is instead explained by the **behavior of PowerShell's [member-access enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375) feature**:

When you access `$response.tags.results.values`, the `.values` properties on the - multiple - `.results` properties (you're using *nested* member-access enumeration) are effectively enumerated as follows:

```sh
$response.tags.results | ForEach-Object { $_.values }
```

In doing so, ***empty arrays* are effectively *removed*** from the output, and you get only *2* output objects (that each contain the *inner* array of the nested ones in your case); you can verify that by applying `(...).Count` to the command above.

The reason is that objects output by a [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{ ... }`) are sent to the *pipeline*, which by default *enumerates* objects that are collections (arrays).
Since **your 2nd `.values` value is an *empty* array** (parsed from JSON `[]` and therefore *not* `$null`), there is nothing to enumerate and *nothing* is output, resulting in effective removal.

Note that the above implies that **collections of collections are *flattened* by member-access enumeration**; for instance, if the property values are 3 2-element arrays, the pipeline-enumeration logic results in a single 6-element array rather than in a 3-element array containing 2-element arrays each.

---

The **workaround** is to to use the [`ForEach()` array *method*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays), which doesn't perform this stripping *if* you target the property by supplying its name as a *string*:

```sh
$values = $response.tags.results.ForEach('values')

@"
Resulting Array"
0 : $($values[0])
1 : $($values[1])
2 : $($values[2])
"@
```

Note that your non-empty `.values` properties are actually *nested* arrays; to shed the outer array, use `$values[0][0]`, `$values[1][0]`, and `$values[2][0]`.

**Caveat**: The workaround is only effective if you **access the property by name *string*** - `.ForEach('values')`; the seemingly equivalent *script-block* based command,
`.ForEach({ $_.values })` again removes empty arrays, like member-access enumeration and the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet; **alternatively**, however, you can work around that by **wrapping the script-block output in an auxiliary, temporary single-element array** that preserves the original arrays, using the unary form of `,` the [array constructor operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#comma-operator-):
`.ForEach({ , $_.values })`
You could also use the same technique with the - slower - `ForEach-Object` *cmdlet*.