# How do I edit the values of imported CSV variable with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, member-enumeration, member-access-enumeration

The below script is an example of me importing a CSV file, trying to edit one of the values, then checking the value.

```
$Animal_Farm = Import-CSV "Test.csv"

Echo "The Data"
$Animal_Farm

Echo "`n`n`n"

Echo "Dog's Status"
$Animal_Farm.Status[1]
Echo "`n`n`n"

Echo "Updating Dog's Status to Employed"
$Animal_Farm.Status[1] = "Employed"
Echo "`n`n`n"

Echo "Dog's Status"
$Animal_Farm.Status[1]
```

This is the output, the data is unchanged and Dog's status is still Redundant.

```
The Data

Animal Ocupation    Status   
------ ---------    ------   
Cat    Construction Employed 
Dog    Professional Redundant
Rat    GP           Employed 




Dog's Status
Redundant




Updating Dog's Status to Employed




Dog's Status
Redundant
```

How do I edit the data imported? My plan is to feed the modified data into a JSON file.

This is the CSV file contents

```
Animal,Ocupation,Status
Cat,Construction,Employed
Dog,Professional,Redundant
Rat,GP,Employed
```

Comment: Change `$Animal_Farm.Status[1] = "Employed"` to `$Animal_Farm[1].Status = "Employed"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$Animal_Farm` holds an array of objects, each of which have a `Status` property.

When you ask PowerShell to resolve `$Animal_Farm.Status`, PowerShell goes "huh, the `$Animal_Farm` array doesn't have a `Status` property, let me create a new array from the `Status` property values of each item in the array", which is what you eventually index into with `$Animal_Farm.Status[1]`.

To address the properties of one of the underlying items in the original array, use the index operator directly on `$Animal_Farm` instead:

```
$Animal_Farm[1].Status
```

Answer (score 3):

To complement [Mathias R. Jessen's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68377454/45375) with conceptual information:

As Mathias states, **accessing a property** (`.Status`) **on a *collection* (array)** of objects (`$Animal_Farm`) automatically **returns the property values of the collection's *elements*** in an array<sup>[1]</sup> (assuming the collection doesn't itself have a property by this name, in which case the latter takes precedence).

**This feature, which also works with *methods***, is called ***member-access enumeration***, and is explained in more detail in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375).

**Member-access enumeration does *not* support *assigning* to properties**, however:

If you tried something like `$Animal_Farm.Status = 'Employed'` in an **attempt to set the status property for *all* animals**, you'd get a **somewhat surprising *error***, stating the collection `$Animal_Farm` has no `.Status` property.

- The surprising error message (which is *technically* correct) notwithstanding, this inability to *assign* a (by definition *uniform*) value to a given property of all individual elements of a collection is *by design*.
- By contrast, calling a mutating *method* via member-access enumeration - if available - *is* possible.
- For more information, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49410110/45375) and [GitHub issue #5271](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5271).

If you **attempt to assign a property value via *indexing*** (`[...]`)  into an array of values obtained with member-access enumeration (`$Animal_Farm.Status`), e.g. `$Animal_Farm.Status[1] = "Employed"`, that **assignment is *quietly ignored***.

- The reason is that `$Animal_Farm.Status` returns an array of property *values* that are *no longer connected to the objects they came from*, and while you can technically modify this array by assigning to its elements, the modified array is simply *discarded* after the assignment statement, given that it isn't captured anywhere.
  In short: **You're mistakenly modifying a *temporary array***.
- By contrast, applying the index to the collection itself (`$Animal_Farm[1]` to return the 2nd *object* stored in the collection)  returns an *object reference* whose `.Status` property you can then effectively modify (`$Animal_Farm[1].Status = "Employed"`)

---

**Simplified example**:

```sh
# Create a 2-element sample array.
$animals = [pscustomobject] @{ Animal = 'Cat'; Status = 'Employed' },
           [pscustomobject] @{ Animal = 'Dog'; Status = 'Redundant' } 


# Trying to set the status of ALL animals via member-access enumeration
# CAUSES AN ERROR, because it isn't supported:
#     InvalidOperation: The property 'Status' cannot be found on this object. [...]
$animals.Status = 'Employed'    # !! ERROR


# Trying to set the status of ONE animal via member-access enumeration is
# QUIETLY IGNORED:
#  * What is being modified is a *temporary array* of property values.
#  * Therefore, $animals.Status[1] is still 'Redundant' after this statement.
$animals.Status[1] = 'Employed' # !! QUIETLY IGNORED

# OK: Avoid member-access enumeration, and index directly into the collection
#     to get the animal object of interest, then set its property:
$animals[1].Status = 'Employed' # OK
```

---

<sup>[1] Technically, an *array* of values is only returned if the input collection has *two or more* elements; for a *single-element* collection, that one element's property value is returned as-is. In other words: **member-access enumeration behaves like the PowerShell *pipeline***; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68215551/45375) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64866352/45375) for examples of associated pitfalls, and [GitHub issue #6802](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6802) for a discussion of this perhaps surprising behavior.</sup>